# Getting status of latest record in python

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have below dataframe example:
[image: Dataframe Example]

I want the status of the latest record of product column
query I tried so far:

```
for i in df["product"]:
    process_status = df[df.Processid == i].status.to_string(index=False)
    
    if process_status=="pass":
        print("green")
    if process_status=="fail":
        print("red")
```

The problem is I am not able to get the status of recent data based on time.
Can someone please help?

Comment: Please use text, if possible, instead of using images, in future. It makes it easier for people to locally reproduce the issue faster.

Comment: So, you just want to return 'pass' as '5pm' is the most recent time for the product 'Orange'? Or do you want to get the whole row?

Comment: Just "status" column please, not the whole row

Comment: What do you want when there are two most recent values? Like two times 5pm?

Comment: So my actual data has milliseconds in it so that should be the problem but even if there are two exact same records then display status for both of them